# Game Center(live) only showing local scores

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center

After posting my score to Game Center only local score is visible from my app as well as from the game centre application. 
Weird thing is sandbox worked fine and shown score for all test accounts.

This is the part of my code where i report score:

```
- (void) reportScore: (int64_t) score forLeaderboardID: (NSString*) identifier
{
    if (!_gameCenterFeaturesEnabled) {
        NSLog(@"Player not authenticated");
        return;
    }

    GKScore *scoreReporter = [[GKScore alloc] initWithLeaderboardIdentifier: identifier];
    scoreReporter.value = score;
    scoreReporter.context = 0;

    NSArray *scores = @[scoreReporter];
    [GKScore reportScores:scores withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error:%@",error);
        }
    }];
}
```

Score challenges work fine and i get notified when challenge is completed.

App was released a day ago, is this usual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am seeing the same problem on my game that was released on 27th November. The sandbox leaderboards all worked fine. All the scores are viewable via iTunes connect.
If you look on the apple developer forums there are a few people with similar problems with apps released in the last 10 days.
I've posted a bug report via the Apple 'report a bug' system, but who knows if they even check that. I'm hoping this can get resolved quickly as it is somewhat spoiling my Christmas themed score chasing game :-(

UPDATE: My issue has been resolved as it seems has several others on the Dev Forums. I hope yours is resolved too.